# Obscurating gamma generation for XOR encoding in Java

Tags: java, security, encryption

I am writing a java application which will be compiled into a machine code. This application will be encoding some data using XOR encryption. Gamma for that operation is generated inside the application. I cant generate it randomly, as for another application will have to decode the information and there is no way of sending gamma from the first application to the second one. Thus I need some method of generating a gamma using a key that the second application will be providing. The problem is that this algorithm maybe be found out using a debugger. I want to make it as hard as possible, any ideas on how to do it?

PS. Ive been thinking about creating different java Objects that require an argument and use a lot of system's resources. I would use a getBytes() on them afterwards. This would produce a lot of additional code in the debugger.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use XOR encryption rather than a different form? Security by obscurity is generally not a good idea.

Comment: I cannot think of anything else in my situation. I need to gather data from client and send it back to server. This data should not be falsificated.

Comment: So you just want to send the data to the server in an encrypted format, right? Is it your server you're sending it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to implement your own encryption technique, try using built-in libraries to make your life easier. Since you are sending to your own server, set up RSA encryption using the `javax.crypto` and `java.security` packages.

This StackOverflow answer talks about using RSA in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2027694/2216621

In case you're not familiar with RSA, read about it on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)

Your basic strategy will be create a public/private key pair, and put the public key in the client application. Then use the public key to encrypt the data, then send it to the server. There you will use the private key to decrypt the data.

Comment: Is it safe to use same public RSA key on all clients?

Comment: Yes. Without the private key, it is infeasible to decrypt the encrypted data. That's why it's called a *public* key.

Comment: Please note that unless the data to encrypt is very small, it would be very wise to deploy hybrid encryption: the data is encrypted by a random secret key, which in turn is encrypted using RSA OAEP. Some kind of integrity and authentication (signing the encrypted data) is normally required as well.